# Can bacteria, viruses, and cancer cells be destroyed by resonance?

Tags: molecular-biology, bacteriology, cancer, virus, radiation

Radiotherapy has been used to treat cancer.

Can the resonances by coordinated electromagnetic waves (and/or other forms of waves), of various frequencies, amplitudes and pulse rates, directed from various directions, be used to destroy harmful viruses, bacteria or cancer cells in a human body, without damaging the other parts of the human body?

(*** NOTE *** This question was posted [here in Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239024/can-bacteria-viruses-and-cancer-cells-be-destroyed-by-resonance) too, but is possibly going to be closed in that forum as some claimed it is not so much about Physics.)

Comment: Welcome to Bio. This is definitely Bio and not a Physics question in this form. What do you mean with *resonances*?

Comment: By resonance I mean the molecules/structure of a, say, virus is made to vibrate with increasing amplitudes until the structure gets destroyed.

Comment: You cannot take things like that. Viruses/bacteria are made up of billions of atoms/molecules, all of which have their own resonance frequencies, and most of which may not coincide. To destroy a bacterium/virus, you will have to attack it with all of those billions of frequencies, millions of which will affect/destroy the neighboring cells too. It would be just like you make a man explode just by putting him on a speaker which produces that man's resonance frequencies. ;-)

Comment: Well, we don't have to explode something entirely to kill it.

Comment: ...and we don't have to kill something to make it dysfunctional.

Answer (score 2):

Your question included "other forms of waves" so I'm going to assume that the use of ultrasound to destroy cancer cells qualifies.

A paper published in the British Journal of Cancer in 2009: "[High-intensity-focused-ultrasound in the treatment of primary prostate cancer: the first UK series]"[1](http://eds.b.ebscohost.com/eds/pdfviewer/pdfviewer?sid=77ea5576-b224-49f7-8664-5def5494c426%40sessionmgr104&vid=0&hid=111) describes the use of a "Sonablate 500" device used to treat 172 men with prostate cancers at two hospitals in the UK, and its use is described as resulting in "acceptable short-term levels of cancer control."

However, the paper does lament the deficiencies of research in this area, the number of other treatments available, and the lack of longer-term follow-up to this research.

The answer to your question appears to be yes, with the qualification that this is an example using sound waves, rather than electromagnetic waves - isn't radiotherapy, mentioned in the first sentence of the question, electromagnetic waves?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, I am referring to all forms of waves, including perhaps magnetic fields, which have been used in MRI. I hope more research can be carried out in these fields.